# Can Zabbix generate JVM thread dumps via JMX for monitored Java process

Tags: java

I would like to know if a) Zabbix can be configured to trigger JVM thread dump for a Java process it is monitoring via JMX? b) If it cannot, then can Zabbix trigger JMX operations? (that would allow me to build in the thread dump generation as part of my application and expose it as a JMX operation)

My understanding of Zabbix is not deep, but based on quick google searches, it appears that it has support for monitoring JMX metrics... but I found nothing on JVM thread dump generation.